# Nest's firebase security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, nest-api

I'm trying to mimic the Nest's data/communication using firebaseio.com but by default the security rules are simply:

[image]

What are Nest's security rules so I can test authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which permissions you have requested for your client.

The [API Reference](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/api-reference) goes over which fields are readable or writable given any permissions combination.

Comment: I asked the wrong question but this is the right answer.